# When making a FTP data connection request, if its on an a device with iOS 11 it always times out

Tags: swift, xcode, ftp, frameworks, ios11

We are using this framework ( https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider) and we were adding a new feature to support ftp storage. When we are building the app on an a device with iOS 9 everything works fine and I can list all the files from the ftp server **BUT** when I try to build the app on an a device with iOS 11 I'm always getting a "The operation timed out"

What is happening is that I first open a connection and get response with code 331 and I'm setting a password after that. The second response I get is with code 230 and after that I get a response with code 227 ( entering passive mode) and after the timeout limit the app returns a error saying "The operation timed out"

I searcher everywhere but I cannot find a logical explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must set `FPStreamTask.defaultUseURLSession` to false. Please check [this issue](https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider/issues/89#issuecomment-376448801).

Comment: Yes, I opened that issue and couple a days ago it was resolved. Thank you !